# R: Merging a text variable in by mutate

Tags: r, variables, case

I would like to ask for your advice as I have been struggling with this for a few days and unfortunately without success. This is a school project so I am not even very experienced.
The thing is that I my dependent variable is text based (8 values).
The problem is that I need to use logistic regression.
The variable is related to religion and different churches, so I decided to make it binary by renaming it "Believers" "Non-believers"."Vira_responddenta" is my dependent variable. (im working with real datas)

```
 mutate(Vira_respondenta = case_when(Vira_respondenta=="ostatní Křesťanské",
                                 Vira_respondenta=="římskokatolické",
                                 Vira_respondenta=="českobratrské evangelické",
                                 Vira_respondenta=="československé husitské",
                                 Vira_respondenta=="ostatní mimokřesťanské",
     Vira_respondenta=fct_relevel(Vira_respondenta, "Věřící")) %>%
```

Comment: You can create a logical variable y from x such that y is TRUE for levels "a", "b" and "c" and FALSE for other levels using `y <- x %in% c("a", "b", "c")` .

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm really not experienced. Could I ask you for a code sample?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64975635/using-case-when

Comment: I've tried, unfortunately without success.